# Create a table with one unique field

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to create a table with 1 text column, and I want it to be unique.

Here is what I did:

```
CREATE TABLE Fav {
Category_Name TEXT,
UNIQUE (Category_Name)
}
```

But this SQL won't execute. Why?

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like this is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Comment: @Omar - I am going to guess that you should add a `int` field and make it unique. Even if this query would work, it would mean that `SQLite` would have to compare strings and that is a costly operation.  Besides you do understand that `Car` and `car` both are unique, unless you take this into account, your unique field wouldn't be all that unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `{` and `}` for `(` and `)`.

```
CREATE TABLE Fav (
Category_Name TEXT,
UNIQUE (Category_Name)
)
```